# what is VB vuser and VB script vUser in Loadrunner

Tags: vbscript, loadrunner

What is the use of VB vUser and VB Script vUser in Loadrunner?
Does they have any special significant in performance ?
or they can be use as AD-in for application which requires VB intraction?

Answer (score 1):

These are virtual users developed in the two specific languages VB and VBScript. They are internally converted to cVuser anyway so there is no benefit in using them other than if you prefer these languages over C. Note that these were deprecated in the latest versions of LoadRunner.

Do not confuse with VB.Net virtual user which is a .Net virtual user and not related with the other two.